# Four fair dice $D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4$ are rolled simultaneously . The probability that $D_4$ shows a number appearing on one of $D_1,D_2,D_3$ is

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Four fair dice $D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4$ each having six faces numbered 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 are rolled simultaneously . The probability that $D_4$ shows a number appearing on one of $D_1,D_2,D_3$ is

If $D_4$ shows the same number as $D_1$, then number of outcomes is $6\times 6\times 6$, since each dice has 6 possibilities except the 4th dice. (I took the 1st and 4th dice as a single dice).

Similarly, if $D_4$ shows the same number as $D_2$, then number of outcomes is $6\times 6\times 6$ and so on.

$$\text{Probability}=\frac{3\times6\times6\times6}{6\times6\times6\times6}=\frac{1}{2}$$

But the answer given is $\frac{91}{216}$

Comment: You’re adding up three probabilities of events that aren’t disjoint. $D_4$ could show the same number as both $D_2$ and $D_1$, and you’re counting that possibility twice. Try using the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think in terms of the complementary event. Suppose $a$ shows on $D_4$, then what is the probability that none of $D_i$'s ($i \in \{1,2,3\}$) have $a$.

The probability of this event is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$. So the probability of event you want is 
$$1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$$

Comment: A more correct method to write would be $1-\binom 61 \frac 16 (\frac 56)^3$

Comment: @Aditya not sure what you mean by "more" correct method.

Comment: Well, you select one number out the 6 digits, so $\binom 61$ and probability of getting that number is $\frac 16$. It cancels out in the end, but I think it’s a more complete way of writing (I could be wrong!)

Answer (score 1):

When $\{D_1,D_2,D_3\}$ has

- three elements, just select 3 numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with no repetition and arrange them. Then choose the number of $D_4$. Thus, number of events is $\binom{6}{3}3! \cdot 3 = 360$.
- two elements, $D_1$ and $D_2$ is same or different. If $D_1$ and $D_2$ are same, then $D_3$ must have numbers different with $D_1$ and $D_2$. If $D_1$ and $D_2$ are different, then $D_3$ must have numbers same with $D_1$ or $D_2$. Thus, number of events is $6\cdot 5 \cdot 2 + 6\cdot 5 \cdot 2\cdot 2=180$.
- one elements, $D_1,D_2,D_3$, and $D_4$ must equal, so number of events is $6$.

Therefore, the answer is
$$
\frac{360+180+6}{6^4}=\frac{91}{216}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question using Principle of inclusion and exclusion.

The number of ways in which two dies show the same number $= \binom{3}{1}(6)^3$ because I have to chose which dice uout of $D_1,D_2,D_3$ should show the same number as $D_4$.

But I have counted the number of ways in which $3$ dice show the same number twice. So I have to subtract $\binom{3}{2}(6)^2$

Now, I have subtracted the case where all $4$ dice show the same number twice. So I add back $\binom{3}{3}(6)$

$$\text{Required probability} =\frac{\binom{3}{1}(6)^3- \binom{3}{2}(6)^2+\binom{3}{3}(6)}{6^4}=\frac{91}{216}$$

Answer (score 0):

Fix the number on D4.  The probability of  the event that D1 has a different number then the one on D4 is $\frac{5}{6}$, and this probability is same for D2 and D3. Therefore the event in which D1 D2 D3 has a different number than the one on D4 has a probability $(\frac{5}{6})^3= \frac{125}{216}$. Hence the event that we are interested in has a probability $1- \frac{125}{216} = \frac{91}{216}$.